# Implicit Return in Ruby Returns Errors When Returning Two Values

Tags: ruby, return

Consider the following two code examples:

## 1

```
    # Implicit Return
    def yo
      'swag', 'yolo'
    end

    whaat, ya = yo

    puts ya
    puts whaat
```

## 2

```
    # Explicit Return
    def yo
      return 'swag', 'yolo'
    end

    whaat, ya = yo

    puts ya
    puts whaat
```

The first example returns this error: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end` and the 2nd example works like a champ.

So, this got me curious as I know there a lot of shortcuts(idioms) in Ruby ( e.g. `2 + 2` is actually `2.+(2)` ) and if something is not working right always be clearer in your syntax and take the idioms out.

Thus, my question is how does Ruby handle `returns` behind the scenes as to me this shouldn't throw an error?

Comment: `'swag', 'yolo'` isn't valid code and raises an exception. In #2 `'swag', 'yolo'` are arguments.

Comment: Ok, that's not quite my question, though. My question is how does Ruby handle returns behind the scenes as to me this shouldn't throw an error? I get that example 1 isn't valid. I'm wondering what is happening behind the scenes as implicit returns are valid in Ruby and this code only works if I explicitly return the values.

Comment: I think example 1 isn't treated as return either.

Comment: @cameck: Implicit return simply means that the last expression is returned. But your code is syntactically invalid, `a, b` is simply not a valid expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods (and blocks, and class definitions, and module definitions) implicitly return the last expression evaluated. `a, b` is simply not a valid expression, it isn't even valid syntactically. `return a, b` *is* a valid expression: you are passing two arguments to the `return` keyword. Passing more than one argument, and leaving out the parenthesis is perfectly legal.

For a similar reason, `foo(a, b)` works, but `foo (a, b)` doesn't: the former is passing two arguments to `foo`, the latter is passing one argument `(a, b)` to `foo`, which is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: Could Ruby have been designed so that `a,b` in the last line of a method is treated as `[a,b]`, or would that have caused problems?

Comment: I think interpreter read commands line by line. So it just try to parse `a,b` and fails. At that time it doesn't know if it's in the last line.

Comment: @Aleksey, I expect that is true but it would be easy to check if it's the last line. Granted, it would be messy and really wouldn't add functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be

```
def yo
  ['swag', 'yolo']
end
```

It should work but it doesn't answer to your question

Comment: I'm temped to upvote because of your "but...". All too often that's missing.

Comment: Thank you Cary =). My thoughts were the same like in the Jörg's answer but I was not sure. That is why I have posted workaround answer.

Comment: I just happened to see your comment. Don't forget you need "@Cary" for me to be notified that a comment has been left for me.